# How to fix 1200 ARC Issues When Migrating from Non-ARC to ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am migrating an OLD project to ARC. It is a large project containing hundreds of files. When I run the "Convert to ARC" in the Refactor option I get the following.

[image]

How can I fix these issues without having to deal with them manually?

**SOLUTION:**

Instead of converting the whole project and all files to ARC compatible. I simple ignored all those files by putting a -fno-objc-arc flag in compiled sources. This saved me time and now all the new development can make use of the ARC.

Comment: I guess only manually

Comment: could you post some codes that through errors?

Comment: I guess one option would be to tell Xcode NOT to covert those files and I can just leave them as NON-ARC using the -fno-objc-arc flag.

Comment: You could try AppCode as it is better at refactoring in my experience.

Comment: Does Xcode provide any information about what these 1247 issues are? It would be useful to know what problems it's actually encountering.

Comment: Most of them are saying that remove the dealloc, release and autorelease.